# How to execute command to process blob file in azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, command-line-tool

I have scenario where I want to execute a command to process a file whenever it gets added to azure blob storage. That command can only take local path as input. What is the best way to achieve this in azure?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
The flow is like this:

- We are sending file from UI to Azure Functions
- The Azure Function is storing that file in Blob storage

Now we want to process that file with a command, which can only take local file path as input (we can't use a URL in that command). So I was thinking to use Node.js `tmp` package to create a temporary file on local storage.

But the real problem is those files can have size in GBs so will this cause any issue? Is there any alternative to this?. And also I am not sure if Azure Functions support external commands. Could you please suggest how we can install it?

Comment: *That command can only take local path as input.* So you will need to donwload it from blob? The processing needs to be done on-premises? You lack details in the question.

Comment: Hey @PeterBons I have updated the question with some desc on problem. How this clears your doubt.

Comment: You keep referring to an 'external command'. Is this an application you need to run to parse the file? Could you make it part of your Function App deployment? Otherwise running a specific container with the application installed could be an interesting option.

Comment: External command means the commands we execute in linux terminal or windows cmd. Like cat, ls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current information, Azure Functions sounds like the right tool for the job. If you use a [Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger) you can get the file available in a stream by default.

> The Blob storage trigger starts a function when a new or updated blob is detected. The blob contents are provided as [input to the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input).
>
> The Azure Blob storage trigger requires a general-purpose storage account. Storage V2 accounts with hierarchical namespaces are also supported. To use a blob-only account, or if your application has specialized needs, review the alternatives to using this trigger.

```cs
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerExample")]        
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("trigger-container/{name}")] Stream myBlob,
    string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

If you *really* need the file to be local, you could of course store it on (temporary) disk. It might be more interesting to refactor the code to enable it to work with a `Stream`.

Like Peter stated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521705/how-to-execute-command-to-process-blob-file-in-azure#comment122881942_69521705), you might want to add some details to clarify what the requirements are.

**EDIT:**
The Consumption Plan hosting option for Azure Functions has a (total) storage limit of 5 TB. Storing a file of a few GBs shouldn't be an issue.

> The storage limit is the total content size in temporary storage across all apps in the same App Service plan. Consumption plan uses Azure Files for temporary storage.

Source: [Azure Functions hosting options - Service Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits).

Please be advised that Functions might run multiple times simultaneously for a given instance, so it's best to ensure you have a unique path for each execution.

As far as your 'external command' goes: if you're already developing an Azure Function that processes the file, why would there be a need to run external commands? You're developing code to process the file, you could implement what's needed right there.
If you're developing your Azure Function in a language that has external packages to (help) implement your functionality, simply add them to your Azure Functions project (like a NuGet or NPM package).

Comment: I have added more desc in question. Could you please suggest for the same. thanks

Comment: ```Azure Functions does not support external commands, although you can of course call external API's or webhooks```
Is there any way in azure I can execute external commands(for eg: cat) which needs wget installation? Any other azure service?